# Using cantools generated C files

Tags: c, sockets, decode, can-bus, auto-generate

I'm using cantools in python for decoding some CAN messages read from socketcan. In python, I can read a message from the socket and decode it simply with:

```
message = can_bus.recv()
decoded_msg = db.decode_message(msg.arbitration_id, msg.data)
```

where can_bus is the socket and db is the dbc loaded file.
Now i've generated the C files .h and .c starting from my .dbc file. How can I decode a CAN message received in C using the auto-generated files? I can read the message from socket in this way (in C):

```
nbytes = read(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
```

where s is the socket and frame is where the recived frame is stored.
How can I decode the received frame using the .h and .c autogenerated files?

Answer (score 0):

The cantools generate functions called `..._unpack`.

Their second parameter is called `src_p`. This is where you put in the received bytes.

Assuming you are using the CAN network layer of Linux your code would be something like

```
struct my_message myMessage;
my_message_unpack(&myMessage,
                  can_frame.data,
                  can_frame.can_dlc);
```

This will fill the struct `myMessage`.

In most cases you have to decode the individual members of this struct, i.e. convert the raw (binary) representation into the symbolic value. This can be done by using the  `..._decode` functions that were generated by the cantools.